# Python argparse , add_argument, type = <some function> rather than int?

Tags: python, argparse

In a project I see the following use of `add_argument()`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--somearg",type=make_arg_instance,help='blahblahblah')
args = parser.parse_args()
i = args.somearg.somefunction()
```

in which `make_arg_instance`is a function defined as:

```
def make_arg_instance():
    somearg = SomeClassName()
    return somearg
```

It seems the argument 'somearg' is an `class` object instead of `int` and that's why later a method is called as in `i = args.somearg.somefunction()`.

In most tutorials that I've seen the type of argument is always `int` therefore could someone explain a bit about how to add argument of type `class` or any type other than `int`? Thanks!

Comment: Surely `make_arg_instance()` takes an argument, it won't be a function with 0 arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation for the `type` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type):

> By default, `ArgumentParser` objects read command-line arguments in as simple strings. However, quite often the command-line string should instead be interpreted as another type, like a `float` or `int`. The `type` keyword argument of `add_argument()` allows any necessary type-checking and type conversions to be performed.
>
> [...]
>
> `type=` can take any callable that takes a single string argument and returns the converted value

You can pass in *any callable*, provided it takes a single argument to be converted. `int()` is such a callable, but that doesn't mean you have to use that. If you want some *other* type or want to apply extra constraints to the allowed values, you can specify your own.